# ReactJS: How to set the end date max 2 months after start date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Like the title says: 
I'm looking for a way to let a user fill in a form where they have to set a start date and end date.

The end date can be max 2 months after the start date they filled in.
Does anyone knows a way how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a poorly worded / framed question that is too broad. You might want to read the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions. One tool you could use is [airbnb's react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates) library ... but again, read the docs and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/), a great lib to handle dates and times.

```
const startDate = '20180104'; // could be another format, check the doc
moment(startDate).add(2, 'months')`
```

The lib is really powerful, be sure to check it ;)